# Jquery slider buttons on top of date picker calendar

Tags: html, jquery-ui, layout, datepicker, slider

I have implemented a jQuery date picker on the first line of a HTML table and two sliders on the following lines:

[image]

Unfortunately, when the date picker calendar is opened, the slider buttons are displayed on top of it:

[image]

How can I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using CSS and make sure that the z-index of your datepicker is higher than the z-index of your slider.

```
.ui-datepicker {
    z-index: 2;
}
.ui-slider {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: It works if the z-index of datepicker is GREATER than z-index of slider, so you should update your answer. I'll approve it...

Comment: Sorry, haven't used z-index in a while. For some reason I was thinking of "higher" being "closer to 0". Glad it fixed your problem though!